# I want to insert Rich Text Box at run time on JSP Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using jquery.wysiwyg.js  to make a Rich Text Box.

On page load it's working fine with given code.

```
<textarea  id="optA" name="optA" class="textarea required i-text wysiwyg" ></textarea>
```

But same code i am using to insert rich text box by a java script function it inserts a plane text area.What i am doing wrong please suggest.

Comment: The code you're using to insert the textarea in JS would help.

Comment: var addrow = '<tr><td ><textarea  id="optE" name="optE" class="textarea required i-text wysiwyg"></textarea></td></tr>';
    $('#askQuestion').append(addrow);

Comment: I am using above code in javascript function but insert plain text area.

Comment: I assume it's this http://wysiwygjs.github.io/ you're using. If you scroll down, there's an API call to create a WYSIWYG editor from an element. Perhaps calling that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wysiwygjs.github.io](http://wysiwygjs.github.io/) help to short the syntax issue. Thank you @icke.

Comment: Hi, Are you adding it at Run time or on Server when Page get Renders?

Comment: Yes @ HP's 411 1 add to run time

Comment: What i'm trying.
having a Rich-Text-Box, and trying to add a New One On same Page.
But the Problem is it is not Working.